# Using mediacache + loadbalancer on wowza

Tags: load-balancing, wowza

I am deploying Wowza server and i have a problem that need help.
I have 3 edge server and 1 origin server, I have successfully configured to redirect from origin server to 3 edge server, on edge server using mediacache, when one client play 1 video, origin server redirect to 1 of 3 edge server and save cache on this edge server, I want save this cache to all edge server, can i do that ? How must i do that ?
please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand wowza 4, you can't do that based on wowza system. Of course, you can do it with, for example rsync, but if you manually write something in mediacache, you have to restart wowza. I think you really don't want that :)

If a user asks for a sample.mp4, you have it on origin and on edge1, and the loadbalancer tells, that the user can ask it from edge2, than edge2 will ask for the video from origin, then edge2 will have it in it's mediacache. It works automatically.

Why is it important, that you cache videos on all edge servers immediately?

Comment: if my knowledge is correct is streaming video from cache is bester streaming from comtents server. i want the first streaming video a.mp4 , origin redirect to edge1 and save cache. the second streaming video a.mp4 origin redirect to edge2, i want edge2 have cache of edge1 to streaming without get video from contents server. I do not know that I think that's okay, Please give me advice!

Comment: To stream a video from edge server is faster only when it has it in it's mediacache. Any other events are the same in speed, except the origin server is overloaded.
Can clients ask for videos from the origin server directly? If not, it won't be overloaded ever.
Wowza has built a great system, with the theory of origin and edges. It works well in most cases. So my advice is that you should leave it as is now, it is the best scenario you can do.